# second combobox loads onchange of 1st

Tags: php, extjs, extjs4

I have three combo box 
Onselect of first I want the second and third  combobox  to load with the respected value.
here is my code snippet.

```
{
                           xtype : 'combo',
                           store : 'product.CategoryComboBox',
                           name: 'category',
                           displayField: 'name',
                           valueField: 'idProductCategory',
                           multiSelect : false,
                           fieldLabel: 'Category',
                           allowBlank: false,
                           allowQueryAll : false,
                           forceSelection : true,
                           typeAhead: true,
                           triggerAction: 'all',
                           delimiter : ',',
                           width: 300,
                           mode: 'local',
                           listeners:{select:{fn:function(combo, value) {
                           var attribute = Ext.getCmp('attributes');
                           var feature = Ext.getCmp('features');
                           attribute.setValue('');
                           attribute.store.removeAll();
                           attribute.setDisabled(false);
                           attribute.store.load({
                           params: {id: 5}
                         });
                           feature.setValue('');
                           feature.setDisabled(false);
                           feature.store.removeAll();
                           feature.store.load({
                           params: {id: 5}
                         });
                           //attribute.store.filter('abbr', 1);
                          }}}       
                    }
```

Here the problem that i am getting is i have to select the 2nd and 3rd combo box first ,then selecting the 1st combo loads the data correctly.
And if selecting 1st combo first the options are not loaded on both the 2nd and 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

Use change listener instead of select listener and I think you'll get there.